# How to set FuturedImage to og: image. in gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet, gatsby-image

I using gatsby.js.

I want to set the featuredimage described in markdown in the og: image attribute of the meta tag, but it does not work.

The featuredimage is optimized for different paths by gatsby, but the relative path is set to the physical path before build.

How do I set the path for the featuredimage created by the build?

My React Helmet code (excerpt):

```
<Helmet
    meta={{
      property: `og:image`,
      content: `https://example.com/${post.frontmatter.featuredimage.relativePath}`
    }}
 />
```

My GraphQL query:

```js
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        author
      }
    }
    mdx(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      frontmatter {
        featuredimage {
          relativePath
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 400, quality: 100) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query path of generated image (format is '/static/name') and use it with site root url like:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        author
      }
    }
    mdx(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      frontmatter {
        featuredimage {
          childImageSharp {
            original {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

<Helmet
    meta={{
      property: `og:image`,
      content: `${siteUrlRoot}${post.frontmatter.featuredimage.childImageSharp.original.src}`
    }}
 />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The following error occurred: "-Unknown field 'original' on type 'File'." Do you know the official documentation for original.src?

Comment: This method worked well for me. @Yuwaz: As for documentation you can use the Graphql interface to browse through the available fields of your setup.